# RxView.clicks() dies after onError event

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-binding

Here is a sample Rx chain using RxBindings:

```
RxView.clicks(refreshIcon)
        .flatMap { Observable.error<Throwable>(IllegalArgumentException()) }
        .subscribe(
                { Timber.d("onNext")},
                { error -> Timber.d("onError") })
        .addTo(disposables)
```

After clicking my refresh icon once, this chain will not run again as a terminal event took place. I am guessing I was under the wrong impression that the subscription takes place whenever a click event is detected, and that it in fact subscribes whenever that block of code gets executed.

Question is how can I make my chain execute/re-execute on every click, even after it hits a terminal event? Looking for something intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable` must complete when the first error occur, it's in their contract. In order to have your `Observable` survive terminal event, you will have to dig in RxJava [Error handling operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators). [`retry()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) seems a good fit in your case:

```
RxView.clicks(refreshIcon)
        .flatMap { ... }
        .retry()
        .subscribe(...)
        .addTo(disposables)
```

Comment: As I suspected. If I use a monad, would the chain not terminate? I'm guessing I simply handle the monad in my subscribe() block?

Comment: I added the relevant sample for you. I also removed the monad digression, since it was more confusing than helping. Wrapping in a monad will terminate, except if you write some complicate operator on your own.

Comment: That seems to work. So when observing a hot source, retry will resubscribe, but will wait for the next emission. This is great to know. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could accept the answer since the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the Rx contract when an error occurred the stream will receive a onError event and will terminate.
Unless you actively handle the error, using for example: onErrorResumeNext()